# How can I modify archived objects with NSFileManager?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

This is how I'm retrieving data, saving and deleting in my iOS App. I am also modifying the object by using delete first and then persist. Here is my code for the three methods in my archiver object:

```
+ (id)retrieve:(NSString *)key {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.archive", key]];

    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
}

+ (BOOL)persist:(id)object key:(NSString *)key {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.archive", key]];

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:filePath];
}

+ (BOOL)delete:(NSString *)key {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,   YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.archive", key]];

    return [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
}
```

Right now, `retrieve:` and `persist:` are working fine but `delete:` is very inconsistent; maybe 1/100 times, it will delete properly. I'm not sure if it's my method that's causing the error or if the way I'm getting `filePath` is incorrect.

I've done some research and it seems like I'm not the only one experiencing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you found in your research? Why aren't you using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: If I'm wrong about this being a duplicate, let me know.

Comment: @rmaddy at first, i thought the duplicate may have solved my problem after implementing it with stringByAppendingPathComponent, it is still not deleting properly.

Comment: Use the `error` parameter on the call to `removeItemAtPath:error:` and log the error to see what the problem is.